# How to sum values in a column grouped by values in the other

Tags: perl, bash

I have a large file consisting data in 2 columns

```
100 5
100 10
100 10
101 2
101 4
102 10
102 2
```

I want to sum the values in 2nd column with matching values in column 1. For this example, the output I'm expecting is

```
100 25
101 6
102 12
```

I'm trying to work on this using bash script preferably. Can someone explain me how can I do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
100 25
101 6
102 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an associative array.  The first column is the index and the second becomes what you add to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A columns=()

while read -r -a line ; do
  columns[${line[0]}]=$((${columns[${line[0]}]} + ${line[1]}))
done < "${1}"

for idx in ${!columns[@]} ; do
  echo "${idx} ${columns[${idx}]}"
done
```

Comment: `((columns[${line[0]}]+=${line[1]}))` is more concise and possibly faster in your while loop

Answer (score 2):

In a perl oneliner

```
perl -lane "$s{$F[0]} += $F[1]; END { print qq{$_ $s{$_}} for keys %s}" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is my choice:

```
d = {}
for line in f.readlines():
   key,value = line.split()
   if d[key] == None:
      d[key] = 0
   d[key] += value

print d
```

Why would you want a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and maintain the order:

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$2; b[++i]=$1;next} {a[$1]+=$2} END{for (k=1; k<=i; k++) print b[k], a[b[k]]}' file
100 25
101 6
102 12
```